# SSRS open report with a parameter in a new window

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to open a report with a parameter in a new window. I tried many things but it still doesn't work. It goes to the report window but it's asking to enter the parameter manually. If I hide the parameter, it says the parameters are missing.

My problem with passing the parameter is that It is a `varchar(10)` type value.

I checked other posts but they didn't help. The code that I'm using:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.report.utm.com/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTechn+Info%2fConst_Tel&**ConstID=" & Fields!CONSTITUENTID.Value** & "','_blank'))"
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, try using the following to see if that works for you?

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.report.utm.com/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx&rs:Command=render&rc:Parameters=true&ConstID=" & Fields!CONSTITUENTID.Value & "','_blank','resizeable=1,toolbar=0,status=0,menu=0,top=20,left=20,width=1040,height=730'))"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however the report name was missing in your link so I added it. It behaves the same, it asks to enter the parameter.

Comment: What is Fields!CONSTITUENTID.Value?  If it has special characters in it, you will have to escape them.   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp  is a simple reference.  You may also want to work backwards--get the broken URL to work, then make Javascript to build it.

Comment: The field is a string type, it contains digits with no special characters. I will try to make the URL work with a parameter. Thank you for the link, it will be helpful for the future.

Comment: Can you share what you are exactly using at the moment?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Running the report on Internet Explorer 11. I'm not admin so that's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391(v=sql.105).aspx
The below finally worked. I had to put reportserver? followed by the report path, 
name and parameter.
="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.report.utm.com/reportserver?/Tech Info/Const_Tel&rs:Command=Render&ConstID=" & Fields!CONSTITUENTID.Value & "','_blank'))"

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
="javascript:void window.open(" &"'"& Globals!ReportServerUrl &"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?"&Globals!ReportFolder &"/JournalVoucher&voucher_id="&Fields!account_voucher_id.Value &" ','_blank')"
```

JournalVoucher is my drilldown report and voucher_id is the parameter inside that report.
I pass the value of account_voucher_id from the column from the main report.

And if you have multiple parameters, use the following to add one parameter after another

```
="javascript:void window.open(" &"'"& Globals!ReportServerUrl &"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?"&Globals!ReportFolder &"/TrialBalanceSheetAcctCntrwise&user_id=" & Parameters!user_id.Value &"&acct_centre_id=" & Parameters!acct_centre_id.Value &"&led_id=" & Fields!lid.Value &"&from_dt=" & Parameters!frm.Value &"&to_dt=" & Parameters!to.Value & "','_blank')"
```